# Javascript alert on submit if text field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i want to alert the user if they submit the form with an empty text field

HTML:

```
<form id="orderform">
    <input type="text" name="initials" id="initials" maxlength="3">
    <p class="center">
        <input type="image" src="#" id="submitbutton" name="submit" value="Place Order">
    </p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#orderform').submit(function() {
    if($('#initials').length == 0){
        alert('Please fill out your initials.');
    }
});
```

Comment: try `$('#initials').val().length`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make sure you return false in there somewhere-

```
$('#orderform').submit(function() {
    if($('#initials').val() == ''){
        alert('Please fill out your initials.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('#initials').length` will check if the element exists. Try this:

```
$('#orderform').submit(function() {
    if($('#initials').val().length == 0){
        alert('Please fill out your initials.');
    }
});
```

as lewsid pointed out, you should also return false if you want to cancel the submit

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#orderform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$.trim((this + ' input').val()).length){
        alert('Please fill all the fields');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

but is better if you do this with pure JS not jQuery

```
function funnjsTrim(input) {
return input
          .replace(/^\s\s*/, '')
          .replace(/\s\s*$/, '')
          .replace(/([\s]+)/g, '-');
}

validate_form = function(form, mssg){
mssg = form_errors[mssg] || 'Error: empty field';
var form_to = form.name,
elems = document.forms[form_to].getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length + 1; i++) {
    if(elems[i].type != 'submit') {
        var string = funnjsTrim(elems[i].value);
        if(!string.length) {
            alert(mssg);
            error = 'error';
            return false
        }
    }
}
    if(typeof error == "undefined"){
        alert('Valid');
        return true;
    }
}
```

so in your html

```
<form onsubmit="return validate_form(this)">
```

in this line: `if(elems[i].type != 'submit')` add `|| elems[i].class != 'your input class'` to add exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I'd use e.preventDefault() instead of return false. Return false also prevents events from bubbling and can have unintended consequences if you don't understand this. Also nest that preventDefault within your if, no reason to stop submission if things are good.

```
$('#orderform').submit(function(e) {
    if(!$.trim($(this).find('input[type="text"]').val()).length){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please fill all the fields');
    }
});
```